# If with probability 1 we have $X_n=\mathcal{O}\left(u_n\right)$, when can we say $\mathbb{E}\left[X_n\right]=\mathcal{O}\left(u_n\right)$?

Tags: probability-theory

I hope that this one is not too trivial or maybe it's my lack of sleep that prevents me from seeing it. Assume we have a sequence of integrable random variables $\left(X_n\right)_n$ and let $\left(u_n\right)_n\in\left(\mathbb{R_+^{\star}}\right)^{\mathbb{N}^{\star}}$ such that with probability $1$ we have $X_n=\mathcal{O}\left(u_n\right)$, more precisely there exists some $c>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{\star}}\bigcap_{k\geq n}\left\{\left|X_k\right|\leq c u_k\right\}\right)=1$.

What (non-trivial) conditions might be enough to conclude that $\mathbb{E}\left[X_n\right]=\mathcal{O}\left(u_n\right)$ (not necessarily the same multiplicative constant), *ie* that $\left(\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X_n\right]}{u_n}\right)_n$ is bounded?

The only thing that I managed to find is to assume that $\frac{\left|X_n\right|}{u_n} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{\left|X_n\right| > c u_n\right\}}$ is dominated by some positive integrable random variable that is independent of $n$ and then apply reverse Fatou.

**EDIT:** another possibility which follows from the last idea: assuming that $\inf_n u_n > 0$ and that $\left(X_n\right)_n$ is dominated by some $X$ which is positive and integrable and does not depend on $n$, but then this kills the use of such a result for sequences converging to zero.

Comment: Can you state precisely what $\mathbb E[X_n]=\mathcal O(u_n)$ would mean, like for $X_n=\mathcal O(u_n)$? One problem I see here is that $X_n$ is a sequence of functions (random variables) while $\mathbb E[X_n]$ is a sequence of numbers, so the same result may not apply.

Comment: @Math1000 : Done, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Bbb P (m) = 2^{-m}$ and $X_k (m) := \begin{cases}
2^k \cdot k \cdot u_k &: k < m\\
u_k &: k\geq m
\end{cases}$

By construction
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \{ \vert X_n \vert \leq u_n \}:=\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N} \bigcap_{k \geq n} \{ \vert X_k \vert \leq u_k \} = \Bbb N$$
thus $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \{ \vert X_n \vert \leq u_n \}$ has probability one. But
$$\Bbb E [X_k] = \sum_{m>k} k u_k 2^k 2^{-m} +\sum_{m=1}^k u_m 2^{-m} = k \cdot u_k  +\sum_{m=1}^k u_m 2^{-m} \geq k \cdot u_k$$
Thus
$$\frac{\vert \Bbb E [X_k] \vert}{u_k} \geq k \to \infty $$

Thus without further assumptions you can not conclude the desired.

Comment: I can indeed imagine that there can be counterexamples, however the question is about finding mild conditions under which the statement holds :-)